# How to read local json file based on ID in ios swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4.2

I am implementing songs(text only) application in ios native in offline mode. I am creating local JSON files to read the data from those files. I am using the following JSON file but I don't know is it the right format for developing this application. But I want to know how to read the particular song title and text based on SongID when the user clicked on Next and Previous Buttons

My Tasks:
1. Need to implement NextSong and PreviousSong Buttons
2. Need to show the title of the songs list

```
{
  “Telugu_songs“:[
     {
       “Id”: 1,
       “Title”: “song1 title”,
       “Text”: “song1 sample text”
     },
     {
       “Id”: 2,
       “Title”: “song2 title”,
       “Text”: “song2 sample text”
     },
    {
       “Id”: 3,
       “Title”: “song3 title”,
       “Text”: “song3 sample text”
     },
  ],

“English_songs“:[
     {
       “Id”: 1,
       “Title”: “song1 title”,
       “Text”: “song1 sample text”
     },
     {
       “Id”: 2,
       “Title”: “song2 title”,
       “Text”: “song2 sample text”
     },
    {
       “Id”: 3,
       “Title”: “song3 title”,
       “Text”: “song3 sample text”
     },
  ],

“Hindi_songs“:[
     {
       “Id”: 1,
       “Title”: “song1 title”,
       “Text”: “song1 sample text”
     },
     {
       “Id”: 2,
       “Title”: “song2 title”,
       “Text”: “song2 sample text”
     },
    {
       “Id”: 3,
       “Title”: “song3 title”,
       “Text”: “song3 sample text”
     },
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to name the keys with starting lowercase letter to avoid explicit `CodingKeys`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON format is correct, just the double quotes you used to wrap keys and values seems wrong. Here is your working JSON:

```
{
"Telugu_songs": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Title": "song1 title",
        "Text": "song1 sample text"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Title": "song2 title",
        "Text": "song2 sample text"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Title": "song3 title",
        "Text": "song3 sample text"
    }
],

"English_songs": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Title": "song1 title",
        "Text": "song1 sample text"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Title": "song2 title",
        "Text": "song2 sample text"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Title": "song3 title",
        "Text": "song3 sample text"
    }
],

"Hindi_songs": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Title": "song1 title",
        "Text": "song1 sample text"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Title": "song2 title",
        "Text": "song2 sample text"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Title": "song3 title",
        "Text": "song3 sample text"
    }
]
}
```

UPDATE:

Create a Codable class/struct and then store the JSON data in an array. You can then use increase array index +1, -1 based on your next previous button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to know how to read the particular song title and text based on SongID when the user clicked on Next and Previous Buttons

Comment: You should use codable class/struct for this. There are many tutorials available. Try it yourself and if got stuck, let me know here.

Comment: If you don't mind, Could you please share one tutorial link based on this task